# How do you extract the value of a regex backreference/match in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a text file containing lines of data. I can use the following powershell script to extract the lines I'm interested in:

```
select-string -path *.txt -pattern "subject=([A-Z\.]+),"
```

Some example data would be:

```
blah blah subject=THIS.IS.TEST.DATA, blah blah blah
```

What I want is to be able to extract just the actual contents of the subject (i.e. the "THIS.IS.TEST.DATA" string). I tried this:

```
select-string -path *.txt -pattern "subject=([A-Z\.]+)," | %{ $_.Matches[0] }
```

But the "Matches" property is always null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works for me.  Something else is going on, like using powershell 1 or some strange encoding like utf8 no bom or utf16le no bom.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know why your version doesn't work. It should work. Here is an uglier version that works.

```
$p = "subject=([A-Z\.]+),"
select-string -path *.txt -pattern $p | % {$_ -match $p > $null; $matches[1]}
```

Explanation:

`-match` is a regular expression matching operator:

```
>"foobar" -match "oo.ar"
True
```

The `> $null` just suppresses the True being written to the output. (Try removing it.) There is a cmdlet that does the same thing whose name I don't recall at the moment.

`$matches` is a magic variable that holds the result of the last `-match` operation.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but could you explain what you're doing? Particularly the "$_ -match $p > $null" bit.

Comment: The cmdlet dangph is thinking of is "Out-Null".  But you can also cast the whole line to [void]:  [void]($_ -match $p)

Answer (score 8):

In PowerShell V2 CTP3, the Matches property is implemented. So the following will work:

```
select-string -path *.txt -pattern "subject=([A-Z\.]+)," | %{ $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another option

```
gci *.txt | foreach { [regex]::match($_,'(?<=subject=)([^,]+)').value }
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a much simpler alternative to  select-string that will work better.

In powershell,

1. `$sample="blah blah subject=THIS.IS.TEST.DATA, blah blah blah"`
2. `$sample -match "subject=([A-Z\.]+),"`
3. `$matches[1]` will have the substring you are looking for.

This works on Windows 10.0.16299 version

Comment: cleanest and simplest solution by far. Should be #1.

Answer (score 2):

Having learnt a lot from all the other answers I was able to get what I want using the following line:

```
gci *.txt | gc | %{ [regex]::matches($_, "subject=([A-Z\.]+),") } | %{ $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

This felt nice as I was only running the regex once per line and as I was entering this at the command prompt it was nice not to have multiple lines of code.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  I just checked in v2 and the Matches property works from Select-String.  So in the future this will be less painful for you.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code you are typing is that select-string does not pass down the actual Regex object.  Instead it passes a different class called MatchInfo which does not have the actual regex matches information.

If you only want to run the regex once, you will have to roll you're own function which isn't too difficult.

```
function Select-Match() {
  param ($pattern = $(throw "Need a pattern"), 
         $filePath = $(throw "Need a file path") )
  foreach ( $cur in (gc $filePath)) { 
    if ( $cur -match $pattern ) { 
      write-output $matches[0];
    }
  }
}

gci *.txt | %{ Select-Match "subject=([A-Z\.]+)," $_.FullName }
```

Comment: But why does the MatchInfo.Matches property not work?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo.matches(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @dangph, I believe that's a bug in the docs.  You can verify this by running "gci a *.txt | gm".  The resulting type has no Matches property.

Comment: JaredPar, that didn't work for me, but I believe you are right. Try this: "gm -inputobject (new-object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo)".

Comment: I would guess that they just haven't implemented the Matches property yet. After all, I would expect a class called "MatchInfo" to actually contain info about, uh, matches :))

Comment: @dangph, I would expect that as well but there is clearly a gap between documentation and implementation here

Comment: Yes, that does appear to be the case.

Comment: I just check in CTP3, the Matches property is implemented for v2.

Comment: matches can be found in `$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value`

Answer (score 1):

The Select-String command seems to return a ***MatchInfo*** variable and not a "string" variable.
I spent several hours finding this out on forums and official website with no luck.
I'm still gathering info.
A way around this is to declare explicitly a string variable to hold the result returned from the Select-String, from your example:

**[string]** $foo = select-string -path *.txt -pattern "subject=([A-Z.]+),"

The $foo variable is now a string and not a MatchInfo object.

Hope this helps.

ps5 powershell version 5 string strings manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Another variation, matching 7 digits in a string

```
echo "123456789 hello test" | % {$_ -match "\d{7}" > $null; $matches[0]}
```

returns: 1234567