# Is there a way to reuse regex subexpression (non-consecutively) inside same regex expression?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have much more characters inside the square brackets than shown below, that's why I've asked this question.

```
$str="\test directory"
$exp="\\[a-z]+[ ]+[a-z]+"
$str-match$exp
```

Can I somehow reference the first `[a-z]` subexpression by a variable of sort and use that variable in place of the second such subexpression? Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about powershell, but you should be able to put `[a-z]` in a variable on its own, then concatenate some strings to form your final regex.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible (unless you create a variable `$chars="[a-z]"` and use that to build `$exp`).

Comment: But [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614651/how-do-you-extract-the-value-of-a-regex-backreference-match-in-powershell) seems to have a few answers to a very similar question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Which one of the answers? I have quickly looked through them and couldn't see a connection.